# MODX: Snippet strips and hangs string when parsing the vars

Tags: parsing, html-parsing, code-snippets, modx, modx-evolution

i have a snippet call like this:

```
[!mysnippet?&content=`[*content*]` !]
```

What happen is that, if i send some html like this:

```
[!mysnippet?&content=`<p color='red'>Yeah</p>` !]
```

it will return this:

```
<p colo
```

the [test only] snippet code (mysnippet) is:

```
<?php
return $content;
?>
```

Why is this happening?
My actual snippet is converting html to pdf, so i really need this.

Thank you all ;D

EDIT: I'm using Modx Evo 1.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MODx Evolution has a limitation whereby you can't use "=" (equals signs) in Snippet parameter values. Best solution is to place the content in a chunk or TV and then call it. This is not an issue in MODx Revolution.